# What is the difference between active and setFocus() in bright script?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to Roku world, I'm writing the two textboxes. TextEditbox1 active = true to display a cursor and down key to press, Another texteditbox2 active = true that time texteditbox1 is hidden then Texteditbox2 cursor is displayed. The issue is that. The similar operation I perform with two-button using setFocus() instead of active. it's perfectly working. But I tried to maintain the down key and up key with two textboxes using the Active attribute. It is possible?

I Tried to below things.

```
TextEditBox1  active = true cursor is displayed

TextEditBox2 active = true cursor is displayed and TextEditBox1 cursor is hidden
```

I same operation with two-button it's working successfully.

```
Button1 setfocus true focus is available

Button2 setfocus true focus is available and Button1 setfocus is hidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stupid BUT:

- `active` only shows that blinking cursor in the TextEditBox

when

- `setFocus()` gives it actual focus, when TextEditBox processes `keyPress` event

In my opinion, the only way to use it properly is to imitate focusing on that component, by setting `active=true` without really giving it, because it blocks all the key events. You might make a wrapper-component, which receives focus and then sets `active=true` without passing it down. And(for example) such component would show KeyboardDialog when the user presses the 'OK' button.

UPD:

`clearOnDownKey="false"` might save you from this pain

Comment: Here I successfully maintain But, First I'm in the textbox and open dialog box to store value and press down key to set button focus. again I press UP key to Focus textbox and again down key. Here value automatically remove and focus not transfer.

Comment: Thank you this is working for me. I set clearOnDownKey="false". is not removing data from textbox. thank you again